# Dfficulties getting my first Integration Test right with Python

Tags: python, testing, integration-testing

When executing my integration test, the way it is currently coded, I get an AssertionError. Unfortunately I can´t figure out as to why that could be just yet.

Also a question: Is the choosen Assertion ok, or should are the more usefull Assertions to be implemented?

Any help is greatly appreciated!

**The error:
**

```
(venv) C:\Users\flori\MedibotApp>c:/Users/flori/MedibotApp/venv/Scripts/python.exe c:/Users/flori/MedibotApp/integration_test_login_page.py

FSuccessfully signed in as: 3OrCLD4xx7My6DbjAxsRC0A0Jy83
F
======================================================================
FAIL: test_check_credentials_failed_login (__main__.TestLoginPageIntegration.test_check_credentials_failed_login)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\flori\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\unittest\mock.py", line 1369, in patched
    return func(*newargs, **newkeywargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "c:\Users\flori\MedibotApp\integration_test_login_page.py", line 47, in test_check_credentials_failed_login
    mock_sign_in.assert_called_once_with(email='invalid_user@interim.hos', password='invalid_password')
  File "C:\Users\flori\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\unittest\mock.py", line 944, in assert_called_once_with
    raise AssertionError(msg)
AssertionError: Expected 'sign_in' to be called once. Called 0 times.

======================================================================
st_login_page.py", line 24, in test_check_credentials_successful_login
    mock_sign_in.assert_called_once_with(email='holdt@interim.hos' , password='qwert123')
  File "C:\Users\flori\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\unittest\mock.py", line 944, in assert_called_once_with
    raise AssertionError(msg)
AssertionError: Expected 'sign_in' to be called once. Called 0 times.

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 2 tests in 3.271s

FAILED (failures=2)
```

**This is how my integration test looks like:**

```
import unittest
from unittest.mock import patch
from login_page import LoginPage
from db import sign_in

class TestLoginPageIntegration(unittest.TestCase):

    @patch('db.sign_in')
    def test_check_credentials_successful_login(self, mock_sign_in):
        # Mock the sign_in function to simulate a successful login
        mock_sign_in.return_value = 'user_id'

        # Create an instance of LoginPage
        login_page = LoginPage(root=None, switch_frame=lambda x: None)

        # Set username and password
        login_page.username_text_field.insert(0, 'holdt@interim.hos' )
        login_page.password_text_field.insert(0, 'qwert123')

        # Call the check_credentials method
        login_page.check_credentials(switch_frame=lambda x: self.assertEqual(x, "Home"))

        # Assert that the mock_sign_in was called with the correct arguments
        mock_sign_in.assert_called_once_with(email='holdt@interim.hos' , password='qwert123')

    @patch('db.sign_in')
    def test_check_credentials_failed_login(self, mock_sign_in):
        # Mock the sign_in function to simulate a failed login
        mock_sign_in.return_value = None

        # Create an instance of LoginPage
        login_page = LoginPage(root=None, switch_frame=lambda x: None)

        # Set username and password
        login_page.username_text_field.insert(0, 'invalid_user@interim.hos')
        login_page.password_text_field.insert(0, 'invalid_password')
        
        login_page.check_credentials(switch_frame=lambda x: self.fail("Switch_frame should not be called"))

        # Assert that the mock_sign_in was called with the correct arguments
        mock_sign_in.assert_called_once_with(email='invalid_user@interim.hos', password='invalid_password')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

**This is the login_page class:**

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import messagebox
from db import create_user, sign_in

class LoginPage:
    def __init__(self, root, switch_frame):
        
        self.mainframe = tk.Frame(root, bg='#333333')
        self.mainframe.pack(expand=True)

        self.header_label = ttk.Label(self.mainframe, text='Medibot', background='#333333', foreground='#a087c7', font=("Microsoft YaHei UI Bold", 50))
        self.header_label.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=2, pady=(0, 30), padx=20)

        # Entry fields -------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
        self.username_label = ttk.Label(self.mainframe, text='Username', background='#333333', foreground='white')
        self.username_label.grid(row=1, column=0, padx=20, sticky='w')
        self.username_text_field = ttk.Entry(self.mainframe,width=20)
        self.username_text_field.grid(row=1, column=1, padx=10, sticky='e')

        self.password_label = ttk.Label(self.mainframe, text='Password', background='#333333', foreground='white')
        self.password_label.grid(row=2, column=0, padx=20, pady=10, sticky='w')
        self.password_text_field = ttk.Entry(self.mainframe, show="*",width=20)
        self.password_text_field.grid(row=2, column=1, padx=10, pady=10, sticky='e')

        # Login Button -------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
        login_button = tk.Button(self.mainframe, text='Login', relief='flat', background='#4C4273', foreground='white', width='12', command=lambda: self.check_credentials(switch_frame))
        login_button.grid(row=3, column=0, pady=10, padx=20, sticky='w')

    # Functions -------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
    def check_credentials(self, switch_frame):
        username = self.username_text_field.get()
        password = self.password_text_field.get()
        #if username == "admin" and password == "admin":
        #    switch_frame("Home")
        #else:
        #    messagebox.showerror("Login Error", "Invalid username or password")
        #self.clear_fields()
        if username == "" or password == "":
            messagebox.showerror("Login Error", "Invalid username or password")
        else:
            user_id = sign_in(email = username, password = password)
            if user_id:
                switch_frame("Home")
            else:
                messagebox.showerror("Login Error", "Invalid username or password")                 
            self.clear_fields()                                      
            
    def clear_fields(self):
        self.username_text_field.delete(0, 'end')

        self.password_text_field.delete(0, 'end')
```

**This is the db class:**

```
import firebase_admin
from firebase_admin import credentials, auth
from firebase_admin import firestore
from firebase_admin.exceptions import FirebaseError
from request import Request
cred = credentials.Certificate("serviceAccountKey.json")
firebase_admin.initialize_app(cred)

db = firestore.client()
current_user = ''

#db.collection('medications').add({'name':'paracetamol', 'dose':400})

#Authentication
def sign_in(email, password):
    global current_user # global variable
    try:
        user = auth.get_user_by_email(email)
        print('Successfully signed in as:', user.uid)
        current_user = email
        return user.uid
    #except auth.AuthError as e:
    except FirebaseError as e:
       # print('Error signing in':, e)
        return None

#create user
def create_user(email, password):
    try:
        user = auth.create_user(
            email=email,
            password=password
        )
        print('Successfully created user:', user.uid)
        return user.uid
   # except firebase_admin.auth.AuthError as e:
    except FirebaseError as e:
        print('Error creating user:', e)
        return None
    
def delete_user(email):
    try:
        user = auth.get_user_by_email(email)
        auth.delete_user(user.uid)
        print(f"User {email} successfully deleted.")
    except FirebaseError as e:
        print(f"Error deleting user {email}: {e}")
        
    
def get_current_user_email():
    return current_user

    
def clear_requests():
    try:
        requests_ref = db.collection("request")
        requests = requests_ref.stream()

        for request_doc in requests:
            request_doc.reference.delete()

        print('All requests successfully deleted.')
    except FirebaseError as e:
        print('Error clearing database:', e)

#create_user(email="smith@doctor.hos", password="123456")
#create_user(email="jones@doctor.hos", password="123456")
#create_user(email="holdt@interim.hos", password="qwert123")

def sign_out():
    try:
        firebase_admin.auth.sign_out()
        print('User successfully logged out.')
        current_user = ''
    except FirebaseError as e:
        print('Error logging out:', e)
```